# Copy feature output is not accessable by next tool in modelbuilder under ArcGis Pro 2.2.2

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

Is there a bug in ArcGis Pro 2.2.2 because every tool after the copy feature tool is throwing an error [000229](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00226-00250-000229.htm). But when I navigate within the next tool to the output and set it directly as input it is working.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour or got a solution to this problem?

Comment: Specifically, what tools produce that error?

Comment: The near tool for example, I also tried make feature Layer.

Comment: Have you made sure the model is valid using the validate Icon?

Comment: I did and everything is valid but directly when the next tools starts there is the error

Comment: Have you checked the output from CopyFeatures; is the resulting feature class valid?

Comment: what do you mean by that, like I said the whole model is valid and the output of the copy feature tool is green. It has to be valid because I can use it as an input when I navigate to the file and set it as input, only the modelbuilder connection is not working.